# Deleting a blog

Tags: blog

I have a WordPress blog that I forget about. I created it in 2007. I would like to delete it, but the email address I used to set it up is super old—i de-activated the account back in maybe 2008 or 2009. I remember the email address and have tried to guess at passwords, but I have tried a million passwords and no dice.

Is there any other way to get rid of this blog if I no longer have that email address and have no way of retrieving the password?

Comment: is this a self-hosted blog, or wordpress.com?

Answer (score 1):

Without email.  You can't get the password reset link from WordPress.com

It's better to knock the WordPress support  they may help you remove the blog.